# What is the best way to represent constant in YAML?

Tags: java, yaml

I writing a framework where we represent code in YAML and on the fly it will get converted to Java code.

What is the best way to represent java function in YAML?

```
Configuration:
  - name1: "a"
  - name2: computeName()
```

While parsing YAML, I should be able to parse `"a"` as string and `computeName()` as function.

I am looking for best practice so that it will be intuitive and easy for user write YAML.

Answer (score 3):

For YAML values `a` (the quotes are unnecessary) and `computeName()` are both scalars that get loaded as strings. Other scalars normally recognised differently (`true` as boolean, `123` as integer, `2016-08-26` as date).

If you want to distinguish scalars like `a` and `computeName()` that are both loaded as strings, you can try and look at features within the string (like the `()`), but the YAML way of distinguishing different types is by use [tags](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292). In your case you could e.g. use:

```
Configuration:
  - name1: "a"
  - name2: !func computeName
```

Based on the tag (and appropriate tag handling in your program), you can directly create an instance that represents `computeName`. The latter is **the** YAML way of doing things, but arguable `computeName()` without a tag is more readable.

What is more intuitive largely depends on what [your users are used to](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hShY6xZWVGE). Simple rules that are properly documented (whether using YAML tags, or interpreting your scalar strings within the program) are always necessary.